# Sql Server Union Query Optimization

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, query-performance

I have given a task to optimize the below sql query. Currently the query is timing out and causing a lot of blocking . I just started using t-sql, so please help me with optimizing the query.

```
select ExcludedID 
from OfferConditions with (NoLock) 
where OfferID = 27251 
  and ExcludedID in (210,223,409,423,447,480,633,...lots and lots of these...,
  13346,13362,13380,13396,13407,1,2) 

union 

select CustomerGroupID as ExcludedID 
from CPE_IncentiveCustomerGroups ICG with (NoLock) 
inner join CPE_RewardOptions RO with (NoLock) 
on RO.RewardOptionID = ICG.RewardOptionID 
where RO.IncentiveID = 27251 
  AND ICG.Deleted = 0 and RO.Deleted = 0 and 
  and ExcludedUsers = 1 
  and CustomerGroupID in (210,223,409,423,447,480,633,...lots and lots of these...,
  13346,13362,13380,13396,13407,1,2);
```

Comment: Where is this big list of hard-coded IDs coming from? And are you sure you need UNION rather than UNION ALL? Have you looked at actual execution plans to see where the bottleneck is?

Comment: The IDs are comming from the code, the code actually building a string i guess it's passing it and i don't have details why they choose UNION instead of UNION ALL

Comment: Also, I'm not sure I understand how this query could be causing a lot of blocking...

Comment: Run them independently.  Is one the problem?  Is the total longer than the sum?

Comment: please post the execution plan it might help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to insert those IDs to temp table and join it instead of using IN statement.

Answer (score 0):

The key to solving you problem is NOT to fix the SQL, but to fix indexes on your tables.  For example, you should have a compound index on the OfferConditions table with OfferID and ExcludedID.

When you create the indexes on the other tables, remember that if the field is in the where OR the join filter, it should be part of your compound index.

Comment: I don't quite agree.  Start with an index on `OfferID`, and if that gives adequate performance I'd stop there.  Avoid making indices wider than they need to be, and don't index a field just because it's in a `WHERE` clause.